# Como Configurar XAMPP para dominios publicos en servidor WINDOWS

Tags: php, apache, xampp

tengo una pregunta
en un servidor windows como es el procedimiento para dejar dominios funcionando en base a XAMPP.
tengo un sitio en php, el cual funciona correctamente, le cree un hostvirtual y funciona siempre y cuando le agrege el puerto :8080 al final.

pregunta 1,
como hago para evitar agregar ese puerto al final del dominio,
ejemnplo wiwebsite.com:8080

pregunta 2,
como hago para que sea publico ? y pueda acceder como en cualquier otro sitio, lo e intentado con el actual y no funciona, dice error time out (accedineto desde el nombre del host + puerto)

pregunta 3, en caso de solucionar lo anterior como agregar ssl en el dominio, si fuera un servidor linux seria con lets encrypt, pero en este caso desconozco el proceso y mas siendo con XAMPP.

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: 1. Configura XAMPP para que [Apache use el puerto 80](https://www.srcodigofuente.es/apache-server/cambiar-puerto-xampp), así ya  no será necesario agregar el puerto en la URL y aprovecha para agregar el puerto 443, se requiere para SSL. 2. Depende de quiénes quieres que puedan acceder, pero el primer paso es configurar un [host virtual](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/configurar-virtual-hosts-apache-windows.html) 3. También se puede con [Let's encrypt](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2019/01/24/configurando-un-certificado-ssl-de-lets-encrypt-para-apache-en-windows/)

Comment: Yo recomendaría pasar de XAMPP e instalar NGINX, más fácil y ya viene con SSL y HTTPS de base. (A día de hoy trabajo en dockers que corren nginx, es lo mejor y más fácil, en mi opinión)

Comment: hola, gracias por su respuestas. Hago aclaraciones, es un servidor windows, el cual tiene ISS instalado y este usa el puerto 80 y el 443, por esto en apache uso el 8081 y en ssl 444, de esta manera el xamp no se bloquea en los puertos, el host virtual lo cree y funciona siempre y cuando agrege el puerto al final, ahora el problema es que no es accesible desde internet, me pueden indicar como solucionar. gracias

Comment: por lo general es importante siempre mantener una ip para el publico si haces una ip privada el domino cambia

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias cuestiones que resolver acá.

1. ¿Tienes alguna web funcionando en el IIS?

De ser negativa tu respuesta, con detener el IIS ya puedes usar el Apache por el puerto 80 sin problemas.
Si es positiva tu respuesta, y no puedes migrar los sitios web del IIS al Apache, deberás usar siempre el 8080 o otro cualquiera que no este en uso en tu HOST, porque sino se crearía un conflicto de puertos y uno de los dos servicios no funcionaria

2. Para que tu web sea publica debes tener una IP Pública. Para que tenga un nombre de dominio, un servicio de DNS debe apuntar a tu IP para que los usuarios que conozcan tu URL puedan visitarla
3. En esta [página](https://datogedon.com/wordpress/como-crear-ssl-valido-en-localhost-para-xampp-red-local/?__cf_chl_f_tk=.bm_WTljNOyR086TqM2ACezXldxf1bfZZUJz_dyUuEA-1642558395-0-gaNycGzNCD0) puedes chequear como instalar el SSL a Xampp